# How to I get selected row ID when deleted or updated row on button click?

Tags: php

How do I get selected row id when deleted or update row button click?

A button click passes the ID in Demo1.php file.

**demo.php**

```
  <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>
    <tr>
    <td> <?php  echo $row["ID"];?></td>
    <td>  <?php echo $row["Name"];?></td>
    <td>  <?php echo $row["Email"];?></td>
    <td> <a href="Demo1.php" ><button name="Update" id="Update" onclick="Update($row['ID'])" >Update</button></a></td>
       <td>   <button name="Delete" id="Delete" onclick="Delete($row['ID'])" >Delete</button>

 </td>
     </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use `<?php ?>` and `echo` in the Javascript function calls. I assume that you already implemented the two Javascript functions - `Update` and `Delete`.

```
<button name="Update" id="Update" onclick="Update(<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>)" >Update</button>
<button name="Delete" id="Delete" onclick="Delete(<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>)" >Delete</button>
```

I'm not sure why you use both `<a>` and `<button>` click for Update. If you want to pass ID to demo1.php, you just need to add a query string in `href`.

```
<a href="Demo1.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">Update</a>
```

Comment: but function not call.

Comment: If your `ID` is string, you should quote it like `"Update('<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>')"`, otherwise `$row['ID']` is not likely returning and generating the error at the line. You can see it in your view source.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to what @Sithu suggested, but instead of the `ID` I added `this` for each added instance. And add the `ID` to each button name, and just create `onClick` for each name...

Comment: Can you please post what you have done? Otherwise, this is not an answer.